# Each simple real Lie algebra as a representation of its maximal compact subalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am interested in a detailed description of the Cartan decomposition of each type of simple, real, finite-dimensional Lie algebra.  (This is essentially a question about the classification of simple, real Lie algebras.)   If $L$ is simple and real, then the Cartan decomposition is direct sum decomposition $L = K + P$, where $K$ is a maximal, compact subalgebra and $P$ is its positive complement.   To review a bit, this is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ algebra gradation of $L$, so that $[K,K], [P,P] \subseteq K$ and $[K,P] \subseteq P$.

What I am interested in particular is the isomorphism type of $P$ as a linear representation of $K$ in each case, which then governs the Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]$ as a bilinear form on $K \times P$.  I can work this out myself in many of the classical cases, except that I'd probably make a mistake eventually.  I would be interested in a complete table, especially but not only in the exceptional cases.  The references that I found (Helgason and Onishchik-Vinberg) only give $\dim P$ as far as I know, and not the action of $K$ on $P$.  I also found interesting notes by Borcherds that talk the matter through in some examples, but it doesn't look comprehensive.

One particular aspect that interests me is whether $P$ is always irreducible as a real representation of $K$.   (The complexification of $P$ is not always irreducible. ) If it is always true, it seems like there might be a conceptual reason for it.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Atlas software](http://www.liegroups.org)?  I'm not, but it's the first place I'd look for this sort of information.

Comment: Also, although it's not a table, I believe [Adams - *Lectures on exceptional groups*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lectures_on_Exceptional_Lie_Groups/a3XCft6dubIC) constructs $\mathfrak e_8$ in something like this way—but I don't have it to hand, and could be mis-remembering.

Comment: If we take the associated Lie groups, then does this correspond to the infinitesimal action of a maximal compact subgroup on the tangent space of a point  in the associated symmetric space stabilized by the action?

Comment: @IanAgol - Yes, although I didn't know the term until just now, it is the same as the isotropy representation of the associated symmetric space.

Comment: This is known as irreducibility of the isotropy representation. See p3 (=p61) in this 1968 paper of Wolf: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02394607, where it is said to be well-known for irreducible symmetric spaces. Such representations are called s-representations, see for instance this 1996 paper by Heintze and Ziller https://doi.org/10.1016/0926-2245(96)89148-0. I've looked quickly in Helgason but didn't find the statement, anyway.

Comment: For the last part of your question, see Corollary 6.10 of these notes of Ziller. https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/math650/LieGroupsReps.pdf